# How to use acm.jar in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am learning Java by Stanford's Programming methodology videos on YouTube and I'm using the latest version of eclipse not the Stanford version. After I add acm.jar to the build path I still get a red underline under GLabel and error messages. This is what I've got:

```
import acm.program.*;

public class Artistry extends GraphicsProgram {
public void run() {

        add(new GLabel("hello, world"), 100, 75);
        }

}
```

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this? I really appreciate any help. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

its because you also need to add: `import acm.graphics.GLabel;`

**-or-**

if you're going to use other G[something] you can add: `import acm.graphics.*;`

Comment: Yes you want to include the graphics package classes. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GPWah4wbwYs&list=SP84A56BC7F4A1F852

Comment: The docs are here http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~eroberts//jtf/javadoc/student/index.html